# SCCM configuration with .net core 6

Tags: .net-6.0, sccm

I have a server with SCCM 2019 installed that monitors several websites with .net framework 4.8, but the new application with .net core 6 is not possible to configure and does not present the list of options.

Would anyone have a link, article or something like that to help me configure it?

Thanks!

We checked each configuration of this for the website and application pool on IIS10 and they are the same (.net framework and .net 6)